# Notification sound not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, notifications

I am using the following code in my website to show notifications (desktop notifications)

```
new Notification('Testing Sound', {'body':'Playing Sound', 'sound':'https://mywebsite/assets/mysound.wav'});
```

I am in Firefox and notification is working fine but the issue is with sound. It is playing default sound of my mac notifications instead of sound path I gave in the constructor.

Am I missing something? Can you help me locating the cause of this issue?

Comment: What does the output say in the browser console?

Answer (score 1):

According to MDN, Notification.sound is not supported in any browser as of Dec 2015; 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/sound